# WSL2 - Running webpack build cannot find npm-cli.js error

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

PhpStorm is giving me the following error in my WSL2 Ubuntu install:

> Error: Cannot find module `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`

Not sure what to do.

Note: PhpStorm will not let me select any folders in `/bin/` where my nodejs exists, it just rejects the file path.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall `npm` ? If that still does not work, try to reinstall `node`.

Comment: Done both, PhpStorm cannot see /usr/bin/ contents.

Comment: please specify a path to a package, not a binary - `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm` or whatever it looks like - in **npm package:** field in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM** page. Does it help?